# C# reading from serial port and storing it in csv in different coloumns

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am trying to read data from a serial port and store it in a .csv file through a c# GUI.
My packet format is shown below:

Header byte | Length | Type | Data | Tail Byte

So there are two types of data

Header byte | Length | Type A | Data from sensor 1(2 bytes)| Data from sensor 2(2 bytes) | Data from sensor 3(2 bytes)| Data from sensor 4(2 bytes)| Data from sensor 5(2 bytes)| Data from sensor 1(2 bytes)……….and so on (till the packet length is reached) | Tail byte

Another type has a format

Header byte | Length | Type B | Data from Accelerometer1 x(1 byte)| Data from Accelerometer1y (1 byte) | Data from Accelerometer1z(1 byte)| Data from Accelerometer2 x(1 byte)| Data from Accelerometer2y (1 byte) | Data from Accelerometer2z(1 byte)| Data from Accelerometer3 x(1 byte)| Data from Accelerometer3y (1 byte) | Data from Accelerometer3z(1 byte)| Data from Accelerometer1x(1 byte) ……….and so on (till the packet length is reached) | Tail byte

Now the problem is to store each of them in a csv file in different coloumns like

Col1(Data from sensor 1)|Col2(Data from sensor 2)|Col3(Data from sensor 3)|Col4(Data from sensor 4)|Col5(Data from sensor 5)|Col6(Data from Accelerometer1x)| Col7(Data from Accelerometer1y)| Col8(Data from Accelerometer1z)| Col9(Data from Accelerometer2x)| Col10(Data from Accelerometer2y)| Col11(Data from Accelerometer2z)| Col12(Data from Accelerometer3x)| Col13(Data from Accelerometer3y)| Col14(Data from Accelerometer3z)|

Col1(next data from Data from sensor 1)|Col2(next data from  Data from sensor 2)|Col3(next data from  Data from sensor 3)|Col4(next data from  Data from sensor 4)|Col5(next data from  Data from sensor 5)|Col6(next data from  Data from Accelerometer1x)| Col7(next data from  Data from Accelerometer1y)| Col8(next data from  Data from Accelerometer1z)| Col9(next data from  Data from Accelerometer2x)| Col10(next data from  Data from Accelerometer2y)| Col11(next data from  Data from Accelerometer2z)| Col12(next data from  Data from Accelerometer3x)| Col13(next data from  Data from Accelerometer3y)| Col14(Data from Accelerometer3z) 
and so on…..

so i was trying to do it for only type A for now as given below:
I defined a list and an array

```
    List<char> list_data = new List<char>();
```

Then I extract the data from the packet in the below function and store it.

```
     private string bytearraytohexstring(byte[] data)
{foreach (byte b in data){
//extract data.....
list_data.Add(Convert.ToChar(b));
list_data.Add('*');
}
}
```

So now I have the data in a list as follows
Data1 * data2 * data3 * data4 * data5 * data1 * and so on
When I click the save button in my GUI

```
              char[] store_array = new char[list_data.Count - 1];
               store_array = list_data.ToArray();
            string filePath = @"D:\data\test_no_8.csv";   

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            string char_array_to_str = new string(store_array);

            string[] spilt_value = char_array_to_str.Split('*');
            for (int index = 0; index < spilt_value.Length-1; index++) 
            sb.AppendLine(spilt_value[index]); 

             File.WriteAllText(filePath, sb.ToString());
```

By the way I have programmed it, you must have understood that I am completely new to this field! 
And not to my surprise I receive garbage data stored all in one coloumn.
I just want to know what possible approach could I use and where exactly I am making mistakes. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You are separating with "*" but it seems like you had intended to separate with commas.

Comment: you will get a single column because you are reading a single byte then adding your delimiter - you later split into lines based on this delimiter so one byte per line.  First things first - I doubt that you just watn to convert your byte to a char - debug into list_data and check that what you are putting in there is what you want.

Comment: Props for the 'field' pun. I got a kick out of it.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have some problems in the way you are writing the string.

First of all you are appending a new line per split in your incomming data. You want to append them as a comma separated strings instead.

Another thing is that you count it wrong. You will omit the last object in your incomming string array.

Try the following:

```
char[] store_array = new char[list_data.Length-1];
store_array = list_data.ToArray();
string filePath = @"c:\temp\test_no_8.csv";   

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

string char_array_to_str = new string(store_array);

string[] spilt_value = char_array_to_str.Split('*');
for (int index = 0; index < spilt_value.Length; index++) {
    if(index == spilt_value.Length-1) sb.Append(spilt_value[index]); 
    else sb.Append(spilt_value[index] + ",");
}

File.WriteAllText(filePath, sb.ToString());
```

This should write your data to one line separated by commas.